# How do I get v-card in Vuetify to take up full height of container?

Tags: css, flexbox, vuetify.js

Please have a look at this Vuetify fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L4r5aftq/

```
<div id="app">
        <div class="address-card-container" style="background-color: pink;">
            <v-card>
                <div class="card-content-container">
                    <div class="icon-container" style="width: 30px;">
                        <v-icon>calendar</v-icon>
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-left: 20px;">
                        <p><strong>Our Home</strong></p>
                        <p>123 4th Avenue N</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </v-card>
            <v-divider horizontal class="mx-4"></v-divider>
            <v-card class="add-property-card" style="margin: auto;">
                <div class="card-content-container">
                    <div class="icon-container" style="width: 15px"><v-icon>add</v-icon></div>
                    <div class="add-property-container"><p>Add a property</p></div>
                </div>
            </v-card>
        </div>
</div>
```

```
.address-card-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 60px;
        align-items: stretch!important;

        .card {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            width: 50%;
            height: 100% !important;
            min-height: 100% !important;

            .card-content-container {
                min-height: 50px;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                justify-content: center;
                margin: 30px 7%;

                .icon-container {
                    .v-icon {
                        height: 50px;
                        width: 100%;
                        color: #009FD4;
                    }
                }

                .add-property-container {
                    margin-left: 20px;
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    justify-content: center;
                }
            }
        }

        .add-property-card {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }
```

It consists of two cards inside a flex box configured as row and space-between:

[image]

I am trying to set the height of each card to take up 100% of the flex box, but it is not working.

If you go to the fiddle, you'll see that I set height: 100%!important and min-height: 100%!important. I also set align-items: stretch!important in the flex box. But the card on the right just doesn't want to take up the full height of the flex box.

How can I make the cards take up the full height of the flex box?

Comment: Adding height:100vh; will do the trick, add it to the div that is holding the card `<div class="address-card-container" style="background-color: pink;height:100vh;">`

Comment: I'm not sure I want to set the container to 100% the view height, but in experimenting with vh I discovered what the issue was: the add property card had margin set to auto which was forcing it to vertically center. I took that out, made a few more adjustments, and got what I wanted. Thanks.